# SQL in PHP Issue with SELECT MAX(field)

Tags: php, sql

```
$getSelect = "SELECT MAX(sid) FROM templateSelect WHERE dj_id = '$user_dj'";

$gotSelect = mysql_query($getSelect,$mss)
    or die("Error: templateSelect - ".mysql_error());

$numSelect = mysql_num_rows($gotSelect);

echo $numSelect;
```

This table is completely empty, but for some reason $numSelect returns a value of '1'. What am I missing here?

Comment: While you are using `MAX`, `COUNT`, `SUM`, etc. on MySQL Query, they will return 1 row after the query ran. Although there is no data on your table after filtered, they still return it with NULL/'0' value.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MAX()` will return `NULL` if there are no rows selected](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) by the `SELECT` statement. Your result set is one row containing `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the number of rows returned by the `SELECT` and the `MAX` value returns one row with a `NULL` value in this case.